# SubDagOperator Invalid arguments were: **kwargs: {'executor': LocalExecutor(parallelism=32)}

Tags: python-3.x, airflow

We're upgrading to Airflow 2.0 and I have the below task:

```
with dag:
    cms_ingest = SubDagOperator(
        subdag=cms_s3ingest(
            DAG_NAME, 'cms_s3ingest', default_args['start_date'], dag.schedule_interval),
        task_id='cms_s3ingest',
        # so that subtasks can run in parallel
        executor=LocalExecutor(),
        task_concurrency=4)
```

but I'm seeing this error:

> airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Invalid arguments were passed to
> SubDagOperator (task_id: cms_s3ingest). Invalid arguments were:
> **kwargs: {'executor': LocalExecutor(parallelism=32)}

in my airflow.cfg file I have the value:
parallelism = 32

which I believe is what LocalExecutor is using https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/executors/local_executor/index.html#airflow.executors.local_executor.LocalExecutor.

Why is this error populating in Airflow 2.0.2, and how should I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `executor` parameter was removed from `SubDagOperator` when the behavior was changed from backfil to the scheduler logic ([PR](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/5498)).

But even before that it wasn't recommended to parallel tasks inside `SubDagOperator` which is why it was defaulted to `SequentialExecutor` (you can read about the reasons [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-74))

Since you are using `Airflow>2.0.0` note that [SubDags are deprecated](https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/12292). You should move to [TasksGroups](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts.html#taskgroup).